# Array of classes won't hold new value

Tags: c++, arrays, class, variable-assignment

Okay so I'm trying to parse information from a file and I have this loop that reads in an unknown amount of 5 number strings that are separated by new lines. ProfDB is simply an array that holds objects of a class Professor. That class has a method (addPrevCourse()) that adds a Course object to an array of courses within that class. CRNDictionary is a function that takes a string and returns a course object, based on that string. Here are the code snippets:

Main:

```
ifstream in;
in.open("File.txt");

string CRNHash = "";
while (CRNHash != "!ENDLIST"){
     in >> CRNHash;
     (*ProfDB[used]).addPrevCourse(CRNDictionary(CRNHash));
```

addPrevCourse:

```
void Professor::addPrevCourse(const Course& newCourse)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 8){
        if (Courses_Taught[i].getCRN() == "0"){
            Courses_Taught[i] = newCourse;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

CRNDictionary:

```
Course CRNDictionary(string CRN){
//search course list for the crn passed, temp implementation
    if (CRN == "12345")
        return Course("Test", "12344");
    else if (CRN == "13254")
        return Course("Test2", "13254");
    else
        return Course("Test2", "BLAH");
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, and print the Professor's array (Which holds the 5 char strings), all the values are shown as 12344 (The first object from CRNDictionary), even though the file has 5 different values. I have verified that CRNHash is getting scanned in correctly, but can't figure out why the value won't change that gets added to the array.

Comment: What is `ProfDB`, how is it declared and how is it initialized?

Comment: Also note that your reading loop will add the `"!ENDLIST"` as a course. You might want to rethink the logic a little.

Comment: Also (and I think it's even more relevant), how is the `Course` class defined.

Comment: Related: Change that condition to: `(in >> CRNHash && CRNHash != "!ENDLIST")`, moving the extraction to the condition check. Right now its unchecked (and that isn't going to go well). You can also lose the prime to empty string. its pointless with the new conditional.

Comment: You aren't showing enough of your code. Most likely, `getCRN()` always returns `0` and/or you are storing the same value into all 8 arra locations.

Comment: Why are you looping inside addPrevCourse?

Comment: @o_weisman Because he wants to find the first unused element in his array. That seems irrelevant (even though it's inelegant).

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm afraid you are mistaken. It is completely relevant. And by the way, this is one reason people should always debug their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because after the first pass of `addPrevCourse` all the array items are filled with the first input causing the `if` inside that function to always be `false` on following passes. What you need to do is either add a `break` in the `while` when the condition is `true`, or keep a member counter in `Professor` to know which is the next empty array cell.

Comment: Indeed you're right, well spotted :) - the missing `break` definitely needs fixing. However, the fact whether he should loop or not is still irrelevant :P

Comment: @BartoszKP I guess I misunderstood your irrelevant comment then :). But it's a good example how ineffiecient can lead to incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. I played with this for hours and couldn't find this haha I knew the problem lied somewhere in these blocks.